# Date Formats In SPSS Script

Tags: date, spss, formats

```
    Dim SpssTextData As Variant
    Dim objDataDoc As ISpssDataDoc
    SpssTextData = objDataDoc.GetTextData("mydatecol", "mydatecol", 1, 1)
```

The result of SpssTextData should is of type Date but when when i read it it return a number ex: "12881203200" instead of "12/22/1990".

Apparently it is a format problem as explained in http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/spss/library/dates.htm in section "Formatting dates for display"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was explained on the SPSS Community forums.  This api does not return a formatted date: it returns the underlying numerical value.

Comment: I found a workaround. Had to convert the date to string. And from there convert it to date again with cdate().

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some time ago this function. Surely it can be optimized.

```
Function spssDateToVBADate(d As Double) As Date
    Dim dias As Double, segundos As Double
    Dim f As Date
    dias = d / 86400#
    segundos = Int((dias - Int(dias)) * 86400)
    f = DateAdd("d", Int(dias), #10/14/1582#)
    spssDateToVBADate= DateAdd("s", segundos, f)
End Function
```